# emacs C-/ behaves like delete instead of undo

Tags: linux, windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, vmware-player

I have installed emacs24-nox on a temporary instance of Ubuntu (on a VmWare Player virtual machine that I am not going to keep for long).

I have run emacs to edit an Apache2 configuration file using:

```
  sudo emacs /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

Once emacs is running, when I press control and the forward-slash key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>), emacs behaves like I have pressed the delete button. I was expecting it to [`undo` my latest changes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoCommands).

Why is this happening?

Note: That same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button behaves as expected for other commands (i.e. I can move the cursor around with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>) - so I don't think there is a problem with the mapping of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to 'emacs C'.

The emacs mode is described as (Conf[Space]). I assume that it might be the mode that changes the binding of this key sequence. I am new to emacs so not really sure.

Any hints appreciated.

**Update** - @Drew, kindly, suggested that the first thing to find out is what key Emacs sees when you "press control and the forward-slash key (Ctrl-/).

So, I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> and it came up with info about DEL.

> DEL runs the command delete-backward-char, which is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function...

So, now we know for sure that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> is bound to the DEL command.

Comment: What does `C-h k` followed by `C-/` tell you? That's the first thing to find out: what key Emacs sees when you "*press control and the forward-slash key (Ctrl-/)*".

Comment: @Drew Thanks for that tip. I tried C-h k followed by C-/ and it came up with info about DEL. "DEL runs the command delete-backward-char, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function...".

Comment: This is probably why emacs also binds undo to C-_, which is the one I normally use for undo.

Comment: Thanks @psusi - that sounds like a good idea. Both C-_ and C-x U work OK. I will have to change my habits.

Comment: You said: *now we know for sure that `Ctrl-/` is bound to the DEL command.* Actually, `DEL` is a *key*, not a *command*. What exactly does `C-h k C-/` tell you? And what does `C-h k <backspace>` tell you? The `<backspace>` key is often handled the same as `DEL` (which is an ASCII Control character (127), also called the `delete` character.

Comment: I have the same problem on a Raspberry Pi running Arch Linux and emacs-nox.  I am hoping to adapt emacs to my behaviour, not the other way around, since on all other machines C-/ just works fine, and C-_ requires 3 keys instead of 2 (+50%!).  Is there no way to reprogram the C-/ to the 'undo command?

Comment: PS - I asked the same question on [emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51977/17538).